# Angular 9 service using Observables/BehaviorSubject to return results by a parent ID

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have looked around and can't find the answer so hoping someone can help.

I am trying to get data (UserRoles) by parent (AccountId), and I want to have a BehvaiourSubject so I can do add/delete without having to refresh data server side. I can find examples when its just a complete data list, but not when filtering by ID.
Below is what I have, but it always returns empty.

```
export class UserAccessService {
  private userAccessSubjectByAccountId: Record<string, BehaviorSubject<AccountUserRole[]>> = {};

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private userLiteService: UserLiteService) {}

  getUserAccess(accountId: string): Observable<AccountUserRole[]> {
    if (this.userAccessSubjectByAccountId[accountId]) {
      return this.userAccessSubjectByAccountId[accountId];
    }
    this.userAccessSubjectByAccountId[accountId] = new BehaviorSubject<AccountUserRole[]>({} as AccountUserRole[]);
    this.http
      .get<AccountUserRole[]>(`${Environment.accountApiUrl}/accounts/${accountId}/UserAccess`)
      .subscribe(this.userAccessSubjectByAccountId[accountId]);
    return this.userAccessSubjectByAccountId[accountId];
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is returning empty because the `subscribe` happens at a later point in time after the `return` due to the asynchronous nature of observables.

I would use the `tap` operator and `switchMap` operator get what you're looking for.

```
import { switchMap, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
....
getUserAccess(accountId: string): Observable<AccountUserRole[]> {
    if (this.userAccessSubjectByAccountId[accountId]) {
      return this.userAccessSubjectByAccountId[accountId];
    }
    this.userAccessSubjectByAccountId[accountId] = new BehaviorSubject<AccountUserRole[]>({} as AccountUserRole[]);
    return this.http // add return here
      .get<AccountUserRole[]>(`${Environment.accountApiUrl}/accounts/${accountId}/UserAccess`).pipe(
        // assign the accountId key to the data by calling next on the behaviorSubject
        tap(data => this.userAccessSubjectByAccountId[accountId].next(data)),
        // switch to the new observable created and this observable will be returned by the function
        switchMap(_ => this.userAccessSubjectByAccountId[accountId].asObservable())
      );
  }
```